# pass data from a variable inside function to the variable declared

Tags: javascript, angular, function, typescript, ionic-framework

i'm new to develop and i need help for this question, i want the data of variable regionsFiltered inside function getCountry() globally not only inside the function

```
      export class ShipmentManagementRegionPage {
      countryRegion;
      region;
      mainRegion;
      allRegions;
      filteredRegions;
      regionsFiltered;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events, public commerceFunction: CommerceFunction, public navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage, ) {
      console.log(resgionsFiltered)
      }

      getCountry() {

          this.commerceFunction.Getadm1Shipping().subscribe(data => {
            this.mainRegion = data;
            console.log(this.mainRegion)
            this.storage.get("countryRegionList").then((data) => {
              this.countryRegion = data;
              console.log(this.countryRegion)
            })
            this.commerceFunction.GetGeoData_adm1OfCountry().subscribe(data => {
              this.region = data;

              for (let index = 0; index < this.mainRegion.length; index++) {
                let commonCountryRegion = this.countryRegion.find(x => x.CountryRegionCode == this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegionCodeID);
                this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegion = commonCountryRegion
                let commonAdm1 = this.region.find(x => x.cc_fips == this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegionCodeID);
                this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegion.adm1Shipping = commonAdm1
                let commonRegions = this.region.filter(x => x.cc_fips == this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegionCodeID);
                this.mainRegion[index].CountryRegion.geodata_adm1 = commonRegions
                this.regionsFiltered = commonRegions;
              }
              this.rowData = this.mainRegion

            });

          })
```

Comment: Why don't you put this into a `Service` so that then you can access it anywhere within the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is typescript you will have to declare the regionsFiltered property on the window object:

```
declare global {
    interface Window { regionsFiltered: any; }
}
```

Then you may set it:

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.mainRegion.length; index++) {
    ...
    this.regionsFiltered = commonRegions;
    window.regionsFiltered = this.regionsFiltered;
}
```

Then whereever you are you can use `window.regionsFiltered`.

Comment: i have this error:  property 'regionsFiltered' doesn't exit in type window

Comment: uh oh, you shouldnt have added the javascript tag, I overlooked that this is typescript. edited